# When downloading various usdz files for use with RealityKit, how do I know which child to use?

Tags: swiftui, visionos, visionkit, vision-pro

Want to preface that I'm a SwiftUI dev & complete newbie to working with Vision/ARKit

I'm starting to get into VisionKit and I'm playing around with RealityView and placing entities. From my understanding .usdz files are the go to for getting 3d renderings here. From experimenting with a few various files, It seems usdz each has their own file structure.

Sometimes using the wrong child results in the model being completely blown up. Other times when I add physics and gestures it causes them to not work. I was wondering if there was a proper way to determine which child to use, and also if anyone has an explanation it would be super helpful for my understanding.

```
RealityView { content in
    if let model = try? await Entity(named: "SampleModel").children.first?.children.first {
        content.add(model)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding the children? Usually you add the models and then modify the children if you need to

Comment: @loremipsum for a specific example, using this (downloaded as .usdz)
`https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/dice-48979fb08afc4ad8a3dd17a07c2879c9`. The dice doesn't display or interact properly unless I add the following code. `if let dice = try? await Entity(named: "Dice").findEntity(named: "Object_0") {`. From my understanding, each of these files can have unique structure so maybe the answer is some aren't optimized correctly to implemented right out of the box. Trying to figure out differences btwn using ModelEntity & Entity now. Still learning so apologies if this sounds all far out

Comment: Btw @loremipsum you're OG bro I always appreciate your help on my SwiftUI posts lmaoo

Comment: A ModelEntity is an Entity. An Entity is like a container and a ModeEntity is an Entity + Mesh, Materials and Physics. Rough descriptions... I am just getting started with Vision too never been a huge fan of AR/VR but embracing for at least 14 days lol.